# Single SPA React Application Micro frontend

Tags: reactjs, single-spa

I have react application that is developed in create react app.

Now i am integrating micro frontend using single spa.

I have converted React application as single spa. Working fine.

Problem :

I have another react application which is developed in CRA(create react app).This application also I integrated with Single SPA

Now i need to integrate with main application.

Sample code:

https://github.com/gokulwebdeveloper/single-spa

`registerApplication(
  'weather',
   () => System.import('http://localhost:8500/sample-sample.js'),
  () => location.pathname === "/weather" || location.pathname === "/" ? true : false
);`

Please help me to fix.

Comment: Why not merge both of the projects together?

Comment: Currently we going to start micro-frontend project. So i struck with this

Comment: Not sure to have understood your main issue here @GokulKrishnan.  Do you need a way to layout your project so that we can navigate between your two microfrontend? Or do you need a way to make  them communicate ( exchange data state)? Or something else?